# SAS Infile File location does not exist

Tags: sas

Whenever I use SAS I have to temporarily download it onto the school computer from their university app center. However, for some reason no matter what I do infile will not work for me here is an example of the code I type in.

data whatever

infile '\Client\C:\Users\thatguy\Desktop\SAS work\data1.txt' dlm = ',';

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Your not downloading the app, likely a client that allows you to connect to SAS on their server. Since SAS is on your schools server, your files need to be in a location the server can see. Usually that's some sort of school shared drive. If you want access to SAS at home, for learning purposes, look at SAS University Edition for free from the SAS website. It does have limitations compared to what you'll be using at school.

Comment: I missed the at school part - ask your instructor or classmates regarding access files, it's likely specific to your school set up so difficult to comment.

Comment: Alright thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: If you are using Citrix to connect to SAS running on Windows machine then your path should look like a valid Windows path.  You probably need double \\ at the front instead of just one and you don't want the `:` (colon) in the middle of the path.

Comment: I actually ended up doing that and that's what made it work. Thanks alot for the help!